# How to consume IronPython assembly in C# via Hosting API?

Tags: c#, ironpython

I have read almost every question about this topic on SO but all of them explains the other way around. (importing dlls in IronPython)

I have created a `dll` from IronPython code using `pyc` tool.
Using `myScriptEngine.ImportModule("my_module");` doesn't work so far.

How can we consume the compiled `my_module.dll` instead of `my_module.py` when we are hosting IronPython in C# with Script Hosting API?

Comment: But if you've already built an assembly wouldn't be easier to reference it?

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer Since Python types and CLR types are not fully compatible, I prefer IronPython to be self contained.